# Получить данные из объединенных ячеек Excel Python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe

На входе xlsx файл с данными, некоторые ячейки объединены. Какие-то проблемы при считывании данных. Причем один блок объединенных ячеек отработал как хотелось.
Код

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('1.xlsx')
print(df)
print('')
res = df.ffill()
print(res)
```

Результат:

```
    gggg  2.0   7.0   hh
0   NaN  3.0   8.0  NaN
1   NaN  4.0   9.0  NaN
2   NaN  5.0  99.0  fff
3   NaN  6.0  90.0  NaN

   gggg  2.0   7.0   hh
0   NaN  3.0   8.0  NaN
1   NaN  4.0   9.0  NaN
2   NaN  5.0  99.0  fff
3   NaN  6.0  90.0  fff
```

А хотелось бы:

```
   gggg  2.0   7.0   hh
0  gggg  3.0   8.0   hh
1  gggg  4.0   9.0   hh
2  gggg  5.0  99.0  fff
3  gggg  6.0  90.0  fff
```

Ссылка на файл https://cloud.mail.ru/public/BedJ/TJNmsx1qJ

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas
table=pandas.DataFrame(zip(['a1','a2'],['b1','b2']),columns=['columnA','columnB'],dtype='string')
'''
  columnA columnB
0      a1      b1
1      a2      b2
'''
table['columnA']='valueA'
'''
  columnA columnB
0  valueA      b1
1  valueA      b2
'''
#update криво прочёл вопрос
table.replace('a1','a100')
'''
  columnA columnB
0    a100      b1
1      a2      b2
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решен. Первые ячейки не обрабатывались, так как считались индексами таблицы.

Необходимо при чтении файла указать:

```
df = pd.read_excel('1.xlsx', header=None)
```